# How to format date and price in grid ui-component Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want format start date and end date to dd-mm-y, offer price to xxx,xxx.xx

My column

```
<column name="start_date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd-MM-y</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Date</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="end_date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd-MM-Y</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">End Date</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="offer_price">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Offer Price</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can add below lines in your `ui_component` file

```
<column name="start_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd-MM-y</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Date</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
<column name="end_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd-MM-Y</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">End Date</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
<column name="offer_price" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Offer Price</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

And now you need to create one `Price.php` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Price.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Price extends Column
{

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if ($this->getData('name') == 'offer_price') {
                   $item[$this->getData('name')] = //You can add your specific price format here..
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Did you tried this ?